# Eclipse Keystroke to Slide Block of Text Left/Right

Tags: eclipse

I know in Eclipse you can slide a line/block of text up and down by using Alt+Up and Alt+Down, but is there a keystroke to slide a chunk of text left or right?

Say I typed this:

```
int age = getAgeAtDeath("Years", "1980-12-08", "1940-10-09");
```

Is there any way I can highlight the `, "1940-10-09"` and slide the chunk left one character at a time? I know I can cut/paste any number of ways so I'm really just looking to know if there's a left/right equivalent of Alt+Up / Alt+Down.

Thanks!

Comment: hi @jFrenetic that will indent or outdent the whole line if i'm not mistaken. i'm more looking for just moving a block of highlighted text, but thank you!

Comment: It will move the whole selection, not just a single line. That's the only way to move the text in horizontal direction as far as I know.

Comment: ah, i see what you mean, you're right on the 'whole section' (i was thinking too small at the line), but, yes, i'm looking to go smaller than the line and specifically a block of text on the line. i'll leave this open for now. if you want to add an answer of "it cannot be done" i'll be happy to accept that as "the answer" if no one else chimes in with something that does what i'm looking for. thanks!

Comment: I suspect it shouldn't be too hard to write some plugin that does this sort of thing. Although, I've never been developing for `Eclipse`. If I find some time to develop such a plugin, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no command to do that. I've wanted it at times, too. But if you look at the General > Keys in preferences, you can see that there are only commands for Move Lines Up and Move Lines Down.